# Django model for easier data access

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to develop a healthy model relationship, that makes data access easy.

I have the following models:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

# A player has a name, plays for one team, and can have many roles in this team.
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    role = models.ManyToManyField(Role)

# A role describes what a player does in a team. A role can be shared by multiple players and a player can have multiple roles.
class Role(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

# A match is between two teams, who have chosen a set of players from their total roster (usually not all of them), in certain roles.
class Match(models.Model):
    team_1 = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    team_2 = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    date_played = models.DateField()
```

The Match class is certainly incomplete as I have no access to the subset of players from the full roster, and which roles they actually acted on that match. Do I have to build a Roster class, that inherits Team? Any ideas?

I would like something like this:

```
> match = Match.objects.get(pk=1)
> match.team_1.players
[<Player 1>, <Player 2>, ...] # only starting players and substitutes that entered the match.
```

Instead, of course, I will get the full roster, with all the roles they can play, and not what they actually played that game.

Comment: Is a player's role specific to a match?

Comment: Yes. Imagine an NFL player that can play defense and offense. Depending on the game, they might need him to do that.